# Generate graph from list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chart-web-part, google-chart

I have a list that contains many items and I need a way to add a bar graph that is time based. The list has a date column (of when something has been accessed), and the title column (name of what's been accessed)
i.e. Title, ItemID, Date, Viewer. Its possible that many people have read the article therefore many entries can exist with the same title.

The graph needs to display month on the x axis and the count of items with the same name on the y axis.
Can this be achieved using the Chart WebPart in SharePoint 2010 or Google Charts?
The chart needs to grow automatically in the time direction. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you tried SharePoint chart webpart? Refer this [link](https://sharepointmike.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/using-the-chart-web-part-with-web-part-data-sources/)

Comment: Yes but ran into trouble with counting all the same titles for a given month. I found some workarounds using a 2nd list but you need to have titles categorised I think. The title can be any form of text so cannot categorise in this way.